# Cygwin install NS3 issue

Tags: cygwin, ns-3

I'm trying to install `ns-allinone-3.34` in windows10 with the help of cygwin.running `python -v build.py |& tee build.log` throw this error in cygwin:

```
 (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\bin\HostX64\x64\CL.exe 
    Checking for compilation flag -std=c++11 support : ok 
    Checking boost includes                          : headers not found, please provide a --boost-includes argument (see help) 
    Checking for program 'python'                    : C:\Users\amin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\python.exe 
    Checking for python version >= 2.3               : 3.9.6 
    python-config                                    : not found 
    Checking for library python3.9 in $prefix/libs   : not found 
    Checking for library python3.9m in $prefix/libs  : not found 
    Checking for library python39 in $prefix/libs    : yes 
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\cygwin\home\amin\ns-allinone-3.34\ns-3.34\waf3-2.0.21-c6c9a875365426e5928462b9b74d40b5\waflib\Scripting.py", line 119, in waf_entry_point
        run_commands()
      File "C:\cygwin\home\amin\ns-allinone-3.34\ns-3.34\waf3-2.0.21-c6c9a875365426e5928462b9b74d40b5\waflib\Scripting.py", line 182, in run_commands
        ctx=run_command(cmd_name)
      File "C:\cygwin\home\amin\ns-allinone-3.34\ns-3.34\waf3-2.0.21-c6c9a875365426e5928462b9b74d40b5\waflib\Scripting.py", line 173, in run_command
        ctx.execute()
      File "C:\cygwin\home\amin\ns-allinone-3.34\ns-3.34\waf3-2.0.21-c6c9a875365426e5928462b9b74d40b5\waflib\Configure.py", line 85, in execute
        super(ConfigurationContext,self).execute()
      File "C:\cygwin\home\amin\ns-allinone-3.34\ns-3.34\waf3-2.0.21-c6c9a875365426e5928462b9b74d40b5\waflib\Context.py", line 92, in execute
        self.recurse([os.path.dirname(g_module.root_path)])
      File "C:\cygwin\home\amin\ns-allinone-3.34\ns-3.34\waf3-2.0.21-c6c9a875365426e5928462b9b74d40b5\waflib\Context.py", line 133, in recurse
        user_function(self)
      File "C:\cygwin\home\amin\ns-allinone-3.34\ns-3.34\wscript", line 753, in configure
        conf.recurse('bindings/python')
      File "C:\cygwin\home\amin\ns-allinone-3.34\ns-3.34\waf3-2.0.21-c6c9a875365426e5928462b9b74d40b5\waflib\Context.py", line 133, in recurse
        user_function(self)
      File "C:\cygwin\home\amin\ns-allinone-3.34\ns-3.34\bindings\python\wscript", line 130, in configure
        conf.check_python_headers()
      File "C:\cygwin\home\amin\ns-allinone-3.34\ns-3.34\waf3-2.0.21-c6c9a875365426e5928462b9b74d40b5\waflib\Configure.py", line 175, in fun
        return f(*k,**kw)
      File "C:\cygwin\home\amin\ns-allinone-3.34\ns-3.34\waf3-2.0.21-c6c9a875365426e5928462b9b74d40b5\waflib\Tools\python.py", line 300, in check_python_headers
        dist_compiler.initialize()
      File "C:\Users\amin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\distutils\msvc9compiler.py", line 371, in initialize
        vc_env = query_vcvarsall(VERSION, plat_spec)
      File "C:\Users\amin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\distutils\msvc9compiler.py", line 260, in query_vcvarsall
        raise DistutilsPlatformError("Unable to find vcvarsall.bat")
    distutils.errors.DistutilsPlatformError: Unable to find vcvarsall.bat
    # Skip NetAnim (platform not supported)
    # Build NS-3
    Entering directory `C:\cygwin\home\amin\ns-allinone-3.34\ns-3.34'
     =>  C:\Users\amin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\python.exe waf configure --with-pybindgen ..\pybindgen-0.22.0
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\cygwin\home\amin\ns-allinone-3.34\build.py", line 175, in <module>
        sys.exit(main(sys.argv))
      File "C:\cygwin\home\amin\ns-allinone-3.34\build.py", line 166, in main
        build_ns3(config, build_examples, build_tests, args, build_options)
      File "C:\cygwin\home\amin\ns-allinone-3.34\build.py", line 85, in build_ns3
        run_command(cmd) # waf configure ...
      File "C:\cygwin\home\amin\ns-allinone-3.34\util.py", line 25, in run_command
        raise CommandError("Command %r exited with code %i" % (argv, retval))
    util.CommandError: Command ['C:\\Users\\amin\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\python.exe', 'waf', 'configure', '--with-pybindgen', '..\\pybindgen-0.22.0'] exited with code 2
```

UPDATE: after installing cygwins's version of python3 , get this error :

```
../src/core/model/fatal-impl.cc: In function ‘void ns3::FatalImpl::FlushStreams()’:
../src/core/model/fatal-impl.cc:163:20: error: aggregate ‘ns3::FatalImpl::FlushStreams()::sigaction hdl’ has incomplete type and cannot be defined
  163 |   struct sigaction hdl;
      |                    ^~~
../src/core/model/fatal-impl.cc:165:30: error: invalid use of incomplete type ‘struct ns3::FatalImpl::FlushStreams()::sigaction’
  165 |   sigaction (SIGSEGV, &hdl, 0);
      |                              ^
../src/core/model/fatal-impl.cc:163:10: note: forward declaration of ‘struct ns3::FatalImpl::FlushStreams()::sigaction’
  163 |   struct sigaction hdl;
      |          ^~~~~~~~~
../src/core/model/fatal-impl.cc:179:30: error: invalid use of incomplete type ‘struct ns3::FatalImpl::FlushStreams()::sigaction’
  179 |   sigaction (SIGSEGV, &hdl, 0);
      |                              ^
../src/core/model/fatal-impl.cc:163:10: note: forward declaration of ‘struct ns3::FatalImpl::FlushStreams()::sigaction’
  163 |   struct sigaction hdl;
      |          ^~~~~~~~~

Waf: Leaving directory `/home/amin/ns-allinone-3.34/ns-3.34/build'
Build failed
 -> task in 'ns3-core' failed with exit status 1 (run with -v to display more information)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./build.py", line 175, in <module>
    sys.exit(main(sys.argv))
  File "./build.py", line 166, in main
    build_ns3(config, build_examples, build_tests, args, build_options)
  File "./build.py", line 86, in build_ns3
    run_command([sys.executable, "waf", "build"] + build_options)
  File "/home/amin/ns-allinone-3.34/util.py", line 25, in run_command
    raise CommandError("Command %r exited with code %i" % (argv, retval))
util.CommandError: Command ['/usr/bin/python3', 'waf', 'build'] exited with code 1
```

Comment: It looks like you are trying to build an extension for the windows version of Python using cygwin. This will not work. You must install msvc, the Microsoft c compiler that comes in a window development kit or with a visual studio install. Also you may need to have the full python source installed. You should look for a binary package for Windows rather than a source package  for an easier install process. If you want to use ns-3 in cygwin programs compiled using gcc, you must perform the build using cygwin's version of Python that you install using the cygwin setup app.

Comment: @DougHenderson i installed python3 using cygwin setup app and compiles ns3 again. but still get error. I updated the question

Comment: You might need to install the python-devel sckage too. Also check the gcc version and the ns-3 doc to see if the specify a version, or if the indicate the c or c++ standard they require. Incomplete types could indicate a missing or different include file, or a diff standard that makes something that used to work get reported as an error now. But this is much further than you were before. It may be something to seek answers for here with a c or c++ tag or an ns-3 tag, as it seems to fall in those domains instead of Python or cygwin. HTH

Comment: First things first: if you're using cygwin, you should use their terminal; waf found your visual C++ compiler (CL.exe), so it is trying to build for Windows. It won't work. Use the cygwin terminal; never tested on cygwin, but mingw builds requires a [patch](https://github.com/Gabrielcarvfer/NS3/blob/master/src/core/model/fatal-impl.cc#L31-L54) defining the signal struct.